# Ionic / Angular Leave Page Event

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic v4 page that configures a number of parameters for my application and I want to stuff all those values into an injected service right before I navigate off of the page so they can be used elsewhere in the application. I am using the Ionic Tabs Control / Page for navigation.

What is the best way to trap an event right before navigating off of the current page?

I have played with `@angular/router` `NavigationStart` events but once wired up it fires on all page transitions and I can't tell when I am leaving the desired config page. Or should I be using the old Ionic v3 NavControl?

Or should I just be updating my config service on all changes and not worry about leaving the page?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in the onDestroy lifecycle hook? I think that might just work because the page component might be destroyed when you leave it.

Comment: Ionic does not "destroy" pages when navigating away from a "page". `ngOnDestroy` is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete my original question if I could but I can't. These issues were all with Beta 16 and now that I have upgraded to RC0, the issue has been resolved. Looks like all I was doing was correct but obviously there were nav related bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngOnDestroy life cycle hook which will be trigged when user leaves the View i.e component will be destroyed.

```
**Service:**

clearData(){
  //write logic to clear data
}

**Component:**

@Component({..})
export class MyComponent implements onDestroy{

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.service.clearData();
}
```

For Ionic 4, by default ngOnDestroy won't be trigged when we navigate to another view. you can use **ionViewWillLeave/ionViewDidLeave** to handle observable unsubscription.

By using **this.nav.navigateRoot(['/dashboard']);** component will be destroyed and ngOnDestroy will be trigged.

Comment: Ionic does not "destroy" pages when navigating away from a "page". `ngOnDestroy` is not called.

Comment: Are you using Ionic 3/ionic 4?

Comment: Ionic v4 beta 17.

Comment: use this.nav.navigateRoot(['/dashboard']);, this will destroy the component. https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864

Comment: Revisiting this answer. 1st, I don't want to destroy my pages. 2nd, if you don't use the NavControl, ionViewWillLeave will not fire. Options?

Comment: In ionic 4, you can use angular router instead of NavControl. As per ionic doc, it been present for backward compatability and it may remove in the upcoming release.  Using angular router, ionViewWillLeave will trigger

Comment: Can you provide an example. Your answer here doesn’t even reference ionViewWillLeave.

Comment: I have the same problem with the latest version of Ionic4 (4.6.2). I am using Angular router to load a page. On that page I invoke an ActionSheet and, upon selecting and option there, I am using router.navigate() to show another page.  The new page is loaded but neither onViewWillLeave nor onViewDidLeave events are being fired on the original page.